# Resource file is not generating when exported project

Tags: php, android, chat

I their any chat application api to integrate simple chat in the project, one to one chat. I want to integrate the chat module in my project where the registered user can chat with one another.

I tried [QuickBox](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Eclipse_IDE) and followed the tutorial where I found the github soucre and downloaded it. I am using eclipse IDE and as mentioned in the tutorial I exported the sample-chat project in eclipse but the problem is **R** file is not generating. I have Android 4.3 API 18 installed.

[image]

I am not familiar with android studio so want to build it in eclipse. Is there any another API integration available which is easy to integrate. just want one to one chat like whats app.

Comment: The R file isn't generating because you have a compilation error in the styles.xml file. Please show this file.

Comment: Style file contains **<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">** i removed this and added my supported theme. then style file works fine but gives error to some of the layouts.

Answer (score 1):

your style.xml file have some advance android sdk version style change that style according your android sdk vesion

Answer (score 0):

The R file won't be generated until all xml files compile correctly. If there is even a single compilation error in one xml file, the R.java file isn't generated. My guess is you copied code that attempts to use a style that doesn't exist for the SDK version you use in your project. Either change the styles.xml file to use only valid styles for your SDK version, avoid using styles at all or change the target and minimum sdk in your manifest file such that the used style will be supported.

Comment: Style file contains **<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">** i removed this and added my supported theme. then style file works fine but gives error to some of the layouts.